# PhpStorm Symfony plugin: deployment paths

Tags: symfony, vagrant, phpstorm

How I can set for example ***Path to urlGenerator.php*** if I using deployment connection to my project, and this file is generated on virtual machine. I don't want to synchronize that files to my local computer...

The connection to deployment is through sftp.

Symfony plugin configuration:
[image]

Deployment configuration:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a remote action button and also multiple routing files in a new menu entry. you can now add remote files. just update to 0.11.111

https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/685

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test it